# Vector space dimention of $k^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assuming the axiom of choice:

What is the vector space dimention of $k^n$ where $k$ is a field and $n$ is a cardinal number?

If $n$ is finite then the answer is $n$. Every element of the vector space is a unique linear combination of basis vectors, so if $n$ is infinite then $|k|^n = |k| \dim k^n$. So if $n \ge |k|$, then $\dim k^n = 2^n$.

What about the case $\aleph_0 \le n < |k|$?

Comment: Actually, it can be answered in ZFC: $\dim k^n$ is always $|k|^n$ if $n$ is infinite.  See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49551/dimension-of-infinite-product-of-vector-spaces.

Comment: @theuniverseisawesome What exactly do you mean by $k^n$ for infinite $n$? Is this a direct sum or a product of spaces? Note that by one definition $k^{\aleph_0}$ has a countable basis, and by the other it does not.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I mean the product.

Comment: @theuniverseisawesome Then Eric's comment does not apply

Comment: @BenGrossmann In the answer he links to it looks like they talk about the product. To be clear I mean the set of functions $n \rightarrow k$, with no restriction on how many are zero.

Comment: @theuniverseisawesome You're right, I read something incorrectly